# How to get specific fields using R mongolite?

Tags: r, mongolite

Each record has a lot of fields in my collection, I just want to fetch a small part of them. Is there a solution in `mongolite`?

Comment: Just find the solution vis the source code. `cli$find(..., fileds="{'_id': 0, 'filed': 1}")`

Comment: have you just answered your own question?

Comment: Hmmm, yes. Since I remember the solution in `pymongo`(python API), then I guess it may be similar. The source code confirmed my thought.

Comment: There's also the aggregation framework : `cli$aggregate(pipeline = '[ { "$project" : { "_id" : 0, "field" : 1} } ]' )`